# Python 3 recursion function assignment using is_power and is_divisible

Tags: python-3.x

This is the book we are learning from Downey, A. (2015). Think Python, how to think like a computer scientist, 2nd Edition Here is a link. https://my.uopeople.edu/pluginfile.php/512913/mod_page/content/49/TEXT%20-%20Think%20Python%202e.pdf

These are the instructions for my assignment:

Do Exercise 6.4 from your textbook using recursion and the is_divisible function from Section 6.4.  Your program may assume that both arguments to is_power are positive integers. Note that the only positive integer that is a power of "1" is "1" itself.
After writing your is_power function, include the following test cases in your script to exercise the function and print the results:

```
print("is_power(10, 2) returns: ", is_power(10, 2))
print("is_power(27, 3) returns: ", is_power(27, 3))
print("is_power(1, 1) returns: ", is_power(1, 1))
print("is_power(10, 1) returns: ", is_power(10, 1))
print("is_power(3, 3) returns: ", is_power(3, 3))
```

I have no idea what he wants me to do with the print statements. I have made functions for both the is_power and is_divisible but now I'm stuck.

```
def is_divisible(x, y):
    if x % y == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def is_power(a, b):
    if a % b == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: please go to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and more specifically on [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We don't need to go over all your assignment, you should address a specific issue with the code, what is your ewxpected output and what is the actual

Comment: With that said, simply paste the prints after you functions and run the code. Then check if the results are as expected. I find it hard to believe they will as you implemented both functions exactly the same...

Comment: Thanks. Is that better? As a mechanic I find it better to have all the information at once rather then asking questions later. It's faster and more efficient, yea I admit there may have been some questionable bloatness. but It's easier if you can see all the requirements. I'm gonna end up repeating them anyway, or someone else will ask about them. Now when you say to to paste them do you mean like this?

Comment: The key word here is *minimal*... We are not suppose to care whether it's an assignment or a job. Simply present a summary of what you're trying to acheive and the problem you are facing. Now, put that aside did you try what I said? Also I believe the idea of the exercise is to use recursively the function `is_divisible` to implement `is_power`

Comment: Simply after the 2 functions, in the same indentation level...

Comment: When you say to paste them after the function, you mean under "return false" right. Under both functions or just one? As far as using the function is_divisible to implement is_power I'm pretty sure that's what he wants as well. I'm not sure how to do that. My professor has a habit of asking us to do things we have "vaguely" covered.

Comment: haha that seems like another problem we can't help you with (sadly...). try to read a bit about basic recursion examples to get the hang of it. I will try to show you what I meant in the answer, easier to show than write

Comment: Ok thanks :), I was trying to show you how I entered it into my code but everytime I put it into the comment box it bunched together. I was trying to find a way to format it like it did in the post.

Answer (score 1):

```
def is_divisible(x, y):
    if x % y == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def is_power(a, b):  # function that takes two arguments
    """[summary]
    Write a function called is_power that takes parameters a and b and returns True if a is a power of b.
    Args:
        a ([int]): [a positive integer]
        b ([int]): [a positive integer]
    """
    
    if a == 1:  # base case for first argument being "1"
        return True  # 1 is a power of everything because anything to the power of zero is 1
    
    if b == 1:  # base case of the second argument being "1"
        return False  # the only positive integer that is a power of "1" is "1" itself
    
    if a == b:  # base case of the two arguments being equal
        return True
    
    divisible_bool = is_divisible(a, b)  # takes the is_divisible function and returns True if a is exactly divisible by b
    
    if divisible_bool:
        a = int(a/b)
        return is_power(a, b)  # function calls itself recursively
    else:
        return False

print("is_power(10, 2) returns: ", is_power(10, 2))  # returns False
print("is_power(27, 3) returns: ", is_power(27, 3))  # returns True
print("is_power(1, 1) returns: ", is_power(1, 1))  # retruns True
print("is_power(10, 1) returns: ", is_power(10, 1))  # returns False
print("is_power(3, 3) returns: ", is_power(3, 3))  # returns True (3^1 = 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to think about recursive functions is to start with base cases — usually these are the things you know to be true just by looking. In this case you know two things:

• 1 is a power of everything because anything to the power of zero is 1
  • Only 1 is a power of 1

In code that base case might look like:

```
def is_power(a, b):
    if a == 1:
        return True

    if b == 1:
        return a == 1
```

If `a == 1` this returns true because of base one. If `a` is not 1 then this will look at `b` if `b` is one it will only return true is `a` is one.

Alone this returns True for `is_power(1, 1)`, but false for `is_power(10, 1)`.

So for everything else:

If `a` is not divisible by `b` then it's not power. If it *is* divisible by `b` then it's a power if `a/b` is a power of `b`. You can test the first with your existing function and the second by passing `a/b` back into this function (i.e. recursing):

```
def is_divisible(x, y):
    if x % y == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def is_power(a, b):
    if a == 1 or b == 1:                           # a more succinct way to test base case
        return a == 1  
    return is_divisible(a, b) and is_power(a/b, b) # divisible and recursions report True?
```

Recursive functions take a while to get used to. It can help to add some print statements to the functions so you can see how it is being called.

Answer (score 0):

What your professor wanted with the prints, is simply a way to make sure your program does what it needs.

In python, when you run a file, each line is interpreted one-by-one. A function's `def` doesn't do any effect as Python simply defines it behind the scenes. When a `print` statement is met, it will actually print something to the screen. So what you want to do is:

```py
def is_divisible(x, y):
    pass

def is_power(a, b):
    pass

print("is_power(10, 2) returns: ", is_power(10, 2))
print("is_power(27, 3) returns: ", is_power(27, 3))
...
```

As to your problem, I believe the professor wants you to use recursion with the `is_divisible` function. You should read about how to use recursion (basic examples will be enough for this purpose), and  will try to help with the idea. Let's look at an example:

> We need to calculate `is_power(27, 3)`. So we want to check if `27` is a
>   power of `3`. Now, we know the answer is yes, and this is because `27 = 3 * 3 * 3 = 3^3`. So what we can do is check if `27` is divisible by `3`. But that doesn't still say it's a power of 3... So we then want to
>   divide and keep checking. So we want to check now whether `9 = 27/3`
>   is divisible by `3`. And so on, until we get to..... ?

That's the stopping condition you need to find out. Hope that helps get you in the right direction.